# Returning inputs from a test method in a different order then they are given to a method

Tags: java, arrays, testing

Basically I need a type of delay in returning values:
So if my method SlowThinker is given the strings "Hello", then "Goodbye", then "See you later", it needs to return "" (the empty string), then "Hello", then "Goodbye" (and so forth, always one behind its current input).

So far I tried to save all inputs in an array but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in my implementation:

```
public class SlowThinker {
private String[] sayings = new String[20];
private int i = 0;
public int increment(){
    while(true){
        i++;
        return i;
    }
}
public String transform(String stringToTransform){
    sayings[0] = "";
    sayings[increment()] = stringToTransform;
    return sayings[increment()-1];
}
```

}

I am also using the following as my Tester in a different class:

```
assertEquals("", this.slowThinkerOne.transform("Return This Later"));
    assertEquals("Return This Later", this.slowThinkerOne
            .transform("One More Time"));
    assertEquals("One More Time", this.slowThinkerOne.transform(""));
    assertEquals("", this.slowThinkerTwo.transform("This is the Last Time"));
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the problem? What is going wrong?

Comment: Is it the case that, given N inputs, you want N-1 inputs back (N > 0)?

Comment: Might I point out that the array unnecessarily confuses things?  You are only ever storing one value (the next one to return) and therefore only need one variable.

Comment: increment method could have been `if(true){i++; return i;}` instead of `while(true)`.

Comment: it could have just been return i++; for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `increment()` twice in your `transform()` method. You could fix it by storing the value in a temporary variable.

```
int val = increment();
sayings[val] = stringToTransform;
return sayings[val];
```

Answer (score 0):

The antithesis of functional programming. The return value, instead of being based only on the arguments, is based only on the argument to a prior call.

```
public class SlowThinker {
    private String last = "";

    public String transform(String saying) {
        String response = last;
        last = saying;
        return response;
    }
}
```